# Display a specific form depending on the product category - Woocommerce and Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product, contact-form-7

I'm using Woocommerce and Contact Form 7, and I want to embed a specific form in the product description template, depending on the product's category.

In other words, for every product under the category **"Shoes"**, I want a specific form called **"Contact Form Shoes"** to be displayed in the description area.

Any idea of how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way of making it work:

```
<?php
   global $post;
   $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) $categories[] = $term->slug;
   if ( in_array( 'shoes', $categories ) ) {
     echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="1234" title="Shoes"]');
   }
   elseif ( in_array( 'shirts', $categories ) ) {
     echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="1235" title="Shirts"]');
   } else {
   // not display
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You using custom post type?

If not use, Try this

```
 <?php
 if (in_category('shoes')) { //slug from category
 echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="XX" title="Title FORM"]');
 } else if (in_category('shirts')) { //slug from category
 echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="XX" title="Title FORM"]'); 
 } else {
 // not display
 }?>
```

Here is the complete [list of conditional WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), if the above code does not work, just change the conditional as needed

Comment: Hey thanks for your response! Didn't work, but found another way of achieving it. Will post it as an answer to my original question.